Unable to build xcode project after create turbo module in react native using swift file
I am trying to create a basic turbo module in react native.
Without adding any swift file to the module it is working perfectly. But if I add a swift file to the module without even using it. It doesn't build the xcode project.
Podfile:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '13.4'
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'BasicApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'BasicAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

**Command I am using to install pods:
**
bundle install && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec "USE_FRAMEWORKS=dynamic pod install"
**Errors I am getting in Xcode:
**
Getting the following errors while building in xcode
I am trying to build the turbo module, I know the swift can't be used directly in turbo modules, so I want to implement the functionality in swift and use the swift function in objective-c++ code to export the functionality to react native.
